Open html file and insert a plot in Python
I have an html file called output.html (see the html code at the bottom of this message).
The html file contains the following table.

I also have a file called foo.png that I need to:

open in Python
insert below the table in the output.html file

Here is the graph contained in the foo.png file.

So, the final html file (called finalOutput.html)would look like this:

Is there a way to create the finalOutput.html in Python?
Here is the html code of the output.html file.


Univariate Analysis<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>Feature</th>
      <th>Value</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>0</th>
      <td>Feature Name</td>
      <td>AgeM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td>Feature Type</td>
      <td>int64</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2</th>
      <td>Number of Records</td>
      <td>177607</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>3</th>
      <td>Number of Zeros</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>4</th>
      <td>% Zeros</td>
      <td>0.0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>5</th>
      <td>Number of Missing Records</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>6</th>
      <td>% Missing Records</td>
      <td>0.0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>7</th>
      <td>Minimum</td>
      <td>18</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>8</th>
      <td>Mean</td>
      <td>48.44</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>9</th>
      <td>Median</td>
      <td>49.0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>10</th>
      <td>Maximum</td>
      <td>111</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>11</th>
      <td>Skewness</td>
      <td>0.03</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>12</th>
      <td>Kurtosis</td>
      <td>-0.95</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>




Have you tried any solution? Did you look into bs4 package or any other python packages that lets you modify html code?
Any issue you are facing with those? Please try some code on your end before asking question.

https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/ is best way to modify existing HTML file from Python. If you also control the generation HTML file, consider making it a template, you can then add a placeholder where the image tag should go and can substitute the exact img tag string from Python see https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#template-strings
